# Accessing image outside the src folder in angular

Tags: sql, json, angular

I am creating a project of an online store, however my images are stored outside the src folder. Path : flowersApp => img

Is there a way to access the images stored under this folder ?

Below is my angular.json (assets) :

```
"projects": {
"flowersApp": {
  "projectType": "application",
  "schematics": {},
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/flowersApp",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": true,
        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "./img",
            "output": "/some-package/"
          }
```

Do i need to edit anything else ? Using this, i am still not able to access the image.

Below is the project structure :

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RZJb.png)

I am trying to call the image as (all.component.html) :

```
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
      <img src="../../../../../img/Romantic-Flowers.jpg" class="card-img-top" width="50px" height="300px" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{data.name}}</h5>
        <span>{{data.description}}</span>
        <h5 class="card-title">₹{{data.price}}</h5>
        <button class="btn btn-primary"> Add to cart </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Below is the console window output:

[Console Window output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZNBI.png)

Any idea anyone ?

Comment: Any reason why the path flowersApp > img could not be flowersApp > src > assets > img  (or images)? Then you could reference `assets/images/...`

Comment: Please insert your code as snippets in the question and not as image links. It makes it harder for people to copy your code and test it

Comment: @AndrewAllen Putting it under assets would trigger a refresh as soon as an image is entered. I dont want that. Hence keeping it outside. From where it can be access, but won't trigger a refresh.

Comment: @MatteoZanoni Edited the question, could you advise now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `glob` to do this.

Refer angular documentation: [assets-configuration](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration)

Something like this can be done: *Update your glob & input/output path as per your structure. Below is the sample code for reference*

```
"assets": [
 {
   "glob": "**/*",
   "input": "./img",
   "output": "/some-package/" <- this is relative to outputDir
 }
]
```

Comment: More reference - https://lukasznojek.com/blog/2019/03/angular-cli-different-ways-to-include-assets/

Comment: @Tejashree, looks like I am unable to get the image using this code.

See the output below

Comment: As you have mentioned in angular json "output": "/some-package/", this will be resolved with respect to your outputdir (i.e "outputPath": "dist/flowersApp",). This was just for example. And you try to access it in tag as src="../../../../../img/Romantic-Flowers.jpg". So this is not correct. You could use "output": "." and src="./Romantic-Flowers.jpg" try this once?

Comment: Also, you can debug by testing your url - http://localhost:4200/Romantic-Flowers.jpg or construct it once and try accessing it directly. if you are able to do so, replace the relative path in src="". This will make it easier for you

Comment: Thanks @Tejeshree I was able to resolve the issue with the help of < https://lukasznojek.com/blog/2019/03/angular-cli-different-ways-to-include-assets/ >

Furthermore, I changed 

"glob" : "*" 
"glob": "*",
"input": "./img",
"output": "src/img"=> this, and it solved my issue.

Also had to change the way of calling the src to 
src/img/ImgName

Comment: Just one more query please, since it is updating the /dist folder every time an image is added, is there any possibility of stop the refresh of the webpage again and again. This was the only issue, why i kept images outside the src

Comment: Do you want images to be independent of your bundle? We generally can host the assets on some server then instead of having it in bundle.

Comment: looks like, little bit of hit and trial fixed that as well. I was saving the image as soon as i select the file. That seems to be resolved now. 

thanks a lot for your help :D